# VBA For each loop, type mismatch

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I have an issue where I get the type mismatch error when running my code, I'm trying to store an output of a calculation into an array using the 'For each' loop to loop through the range of cells that hold the value id like to multiply by a static value and then store.

How do I adjust the code to prevent the type mismatch error for the array `GrossHS()`?

```
Sub NetWeightDist()

Dim mltplier As Double
Dim SumGW As Long
Dim GrossHS() As Variant
Dim lngth As Long
Dim Netrng As Range
Dim NetCl As Range

lngth = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

SumGW = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L2:L1000"))
mltplier = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2").Value / SumGW

Set Netrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L" & lngth)

ReDim GrossHS(1 To lngth)
For Each NetCl In Netrng

GrossHS() = mltplier * NetCl.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot assign the result to an array, only to single members.  Why do you issue a `ReDim` in every iteration of your loop - `lngth` doesn't change in that loop. And you need to be sure that `NetCl.Value` is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Put the column L values into an array and iterate that

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub NetWeightDist()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mltplier As Double, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim SumGW As Long, arGrossHS, arNet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        arNet = .Range("L2:L" & lastrow).Value2
        ReDim arGrossHS(1 To UBound(arNet))
         
        SumGW = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arNet)
        mltplier = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2") / SumGW
        MsgBox "Items=" & UBound(arNet) & " Sum=" & SumGW & " Multiplier=" & mltplier
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(arNet)
             arGrossHS(i) = mltplier * arNet(i, 1)
        Next
        
    End With 
End Sub
```